# Pivot tables in mysql columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have table **localbanya** ,I wanted to do pivoting of its column, Here is my table structure

```
Billingid    prod_id     qty
  1            11         2
  1            22         5
  2            11         1
  2            22         3
  2            33         4
  3            11         2
  3            22         1
```

I'm expecting something like this

```
Billinid    11   22   33    Total
   1        2     5    0    2+5+0
   2        1     3    4    1+3+4
   3        2     1    0    2+1+0
```

I have tried this but unable to get the desired result

```
SELECT billingid,GROUP_CONCAT(qty) 
FROM localbanya
GROUP BY billingid;
```

please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't qty an integer column? Put case expressions the the select list, one for each prod_id you're interested in.

Comment: I'm interested in the entire values of prod_id column

Comment: What if billingid 44 suddenly shows up? (A `select`'s returned columns is decided at compile time, and doesn't take table data into consideration.)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application level code

Comment: I guess this post might help you - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns